# How do I extract the search paths for headers in the standard library in Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I am using Clang as a *library* and I would like to extract the paths where the user's standard library headers are.

I can extract this information using the command-line tool. For example, on OSX:

```
clang -E -v -x c++ /dev/null -fsyntax-only

...
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/3.9.0/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
...
```

However, I would like to get it programatically. Something like:

```
// (just an example)
std::vector<std::string> searchPaths = clang::GetTypicalHeaderSearchPaths();
```

How does Clang expose this information?

Comment: You might also be interested in the answer of Sean Silva-2 in [this thread](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/How-to-determine-clang-s-system-include-dirs-to-set-in-ASTVisitor-td4029080.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not that easy, because the set of header search paths depends on plenty of factors, including language, platform, command line options, configure-time settings, etc. Also, usually driver may add additional paths, etc.

There is `HeaderSearch` / `InitHeaderSearch` classes inside Frontend library that do the bulk of the work. You may want to look into `clang::ApplyHeaderSearchOptions` - basically allow it to fill a `HeaderSearch` instance and you could iterate over various header search paths.

Comment: Yes, I have found this to be the case myself. The most robust solution I could find (although certainly not the most efficient) was to create a `CompilerInstance` using the `Driver` class, read off the properties and then dispose of the instances. Luckily I only need to read these properties once.

Comment: @sdgfsdh That's actually not bad at all ... thanks for the tip.

Comment: @sdgfsdh: any chance you could post the source of how you did it? I'm struggling to get it working

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else stumbles on this: with LLVM 3.9.1, it is not enough to merely create a compiler instance and read header search information from there. You have to create the preprocessor as well using `CI.createPreprocessor()`; that's the only place - at least in 3.9.1 -  where `ApplyHeaderSearchOptions` is called, and invoking that function is what you want if you want to get the default header search directories.

After that, you can read the headers from `HeaderSearch` attained from `CI.getPreprocessor().getHeaderSearchInfo()` using `HeaderSearch.system_dir_begin()` and `HeaderSearch.system_dir_end()`.

Thanks @sdgfsdh for the hint on how to get going.