# Get search paths for headers in the standard library in Clang?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++, libc

I am building a programming language using C++, LLVM, Clang, LLDB, user can write `import "@stdio.h"` which is similar to `#include <stdio.h>` so now I need to support C like imports of headers, however I can't get the path to system headers, let alone parse them !

Other answers have gotten old, since llvm and clang API's have updated, I tried this code

```cpp
void print_system_header_paths()  {
    clang::CompilerInstance CI;
    auto Invocation = std::make_shared<clang::CompilerInvocation>();
    CI.setInvocation(Invocation);
    // I can eliminate this line to get rid of an error but other answer suggested creating a preprocessor
    CI.createPreprocessor(clang::TranslationUnitKind::TU_Prefix);
    const clang::HeaderSearchOptions &HSOpts = CI.getInvocation().getHeaderSearchOpts();
    if (HSOpts.SystemHeaderPrefixes.empty()) {
        std::cout << "No system header paths found." << std::endl;
    } else {
        for (const auto &Path : HSOpts.SystemHeaderPrefixes) {
            std::cout << Path.Prefix << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried this command

`clang -v -c -xc++ nul` on windows however this requires parsing the command line output, I would prefer the C++ api

[Linked] [How do I extract the search paths for headers in the standard library in Clang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470241/how-do-i-extract-the-search-paths-for-headers-in-the-standard-library-in-clang)

My programming language : https://github.com/Qinetik/chemical

Comment: In the question I said standard library, but soon I might shift to other libraries like math lib. I need a standard solution to access all the headers for any library user requires